# How to compare the difference between 2 factors in r

Tags: r

Let's say that I have 2 words, Happy and Happiness, and I store them each as a factor. I want to find the difference of those 2 factors, so I will preferably want a function that will spit out yiness, inessy, iness and y in any combination, just iness, or just y.
Let's also consider if the code would work for the 2 phrases:
al,y,a€a%f,a,s$lf,askdʇjg,asfg
and
al,y,a€a%f,a,s$lf,askd/879,876/jg,asfg
both without spaces, notice the only difference is ʇ is replaced for /879,876/.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This question cries out for a [MCVE]!

Comment: Can I suggest `?adist`? E.g. `x <- "Happy"; y <- "Happiness"; attr(adist(x,y,counts=TRUE), "trafos"); attr(adist(y,x,counts=TRUE), "trafos")` - `adist` can show what characters are substituted, deleted, inserted for one string to match another.

Comment: @42, I am new to Stackoverflow, so I do not exactly understand your more complex rules

Comment: At the moment I see no code that would create an R object. Nor do I see (obviously) a clear specification of what a correct answer might be for the unavailable code.( It doesn't seem that complex to me. This is a coding site. We expect code and data.) AND ... use the [edit] facility.